# Database integrity errors when deploying Python(2.7)/Django(1.5) app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-south, heroku-postgres

These days I'm learning Python(2.7)/Django(1.5) via developing a reddit clone. The clone is almost done and works perfectly in my local environment (db = sqlite3). But when I try to host the same thing on Heroku (db = postgres), things go awry.

Specifically, the web app still loads, but the **login**, **logout** and the **comments** part is throwing errors (I'm using django-registrations-redux, django-comments and south).

Since the app is online, you can simply go here to see the error trace:

- login: https://salty-ridge-5419.herokuapp.com/login/
- comments: https://salty-ridge-5419.herokuapp.com/comments/post/

And all my files, including requirements.txt etc., can be found here: https://github.com/mhb11/unconnectedredditapp

It perplexes me that this thing continues to work perfectly locally, but not on Heroku. I'm assuming I may have fudged up South migrations. However, I've been deleting my Heroku app and setting up new ones all day long. Every time I run the syncdb command on a new app, I get the following error after setting up super user credentials post Django-auth system installation and table creation:

```
DatabaseError: relation "links_userprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ...rofile"."user_id", "links_userprofile"."bio" FROM "links_use...
```

I follow it up with `heroku run python2.7 manage.py syncdb --migrate` (i.e. syncdb and migrate together), this time the migration doesn't spout an error. But anyhow, the app nevertheless gives DB errors I pointed out at the start.

I'm thinking I should uninstall South in my local setup, and use good old syncdb for everything.

At this point, there's a ton that could be going wrong with my heroku deployment, so I understand you may not be able to give me a pinpoint solution. But hit me with all ideas you have - I'm open to trying everything, because this thing has now been stuck for me since over 48 hrs. Help!

*Note: If you end up checking out the clone (https://salty-ridge-5419.herokuapp.com/), pardon the text labels which aren't in English.*

---

Error trace from running **syncdb command** after doing `git push heroku master`:

```
(unconnectedreddit)has@has-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/uncreddit$ heroku run python2.7 manage.py syncdb
Running `python2.7 manage.py syncdb` attached to terminal... up, run.8792
CHECKING_HEROKU!
ON_HEROKU!
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_site
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table django_comments
Creating table django_comment_flags
Creating table south_migrationhistory

You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes
Username (leave blank to use 'u8919'): mhb
Email address: bhs@bhs.com
Password: 
Password (again): 
DatabaseError: relation "links_userprofile" does not exist
LINE 1: ...rofile"."user_id", "links_userprofile"."bio" FROM "links_use...
```

Comment: Does it work if you don't create a superuser on initial migrate?

Comment: Still get errors for login/logout and comment part. This time, I opted for "no" when asked about superuser. Syncdb went on WITHOUT spewing the "LINE 1:..." error I posted in the question. Ending lines instead were: `Not synced (use migrations):
 - links
 - registration` 
Next I ran `heroku run python2.7 manage.py migrate`. That ended with: `You have no migrations for the 'registration' app. You might want some.` That's all I did.

Comment: Carrying on from the above, I then typed: `heroku run python2.7 manage.py schemamigration registration --initial`. I received: `+ Added model registration.RegistrationProfile` I then typed: `heroku run python2.7 manage.py migrate registration`. I received: `You have no migrations for the 'registration' app. You might want some.` Errors are still persisting.

Comment: You have to create the migrations locally, commit them to git, and push the code to Heroku.

Comment: Agreed. But once on Heroku, what all sync commands do I need to run? One is `heroku run python2.7 manage.py syncdb`. Any others?

Comment: migrate, like you did above.

Comment: You should also consider upgrading your Django version. 1.5 has been unsupported for years, there is no reason to start a new project using it.

Comment: The reddit clone I'm building came with a Django 1.5 tutorial. That's how all this mess came to be.

Comment: So tried everything anew. Still didn't work. Here's what I did: 1) dropped the entire database locally. Deleted migrations folder. Deleted my sqlite3 database file (which I've labelled `database.db`). 2) Then ran `syncdb`, which gave birth to a bunch of tables and the superuser 3) Then ran `migrate`, 4) Then ran `schemamigration <app name> --initial` 5) Then `migrate <app name>`, which gave an error that app's table already exists 6) So ran a `--fake` migration 7) Committed & pushed migrations to git 8) Pushed to Heroku 9) Ran `syncdb` on Heroku, again got errors on superuser. Back to square 1

Comment: So upgrading Django 1.5, to say, 1.8 would mean a ton of things in my current project might break. If I managed to sew all that back, I'd still be unsure what to do differently when migrating, etc.

Comment: Dropped all tables locally and started from scratch. I found that local set up works perfectly if only `syncdb` is done (without any migrations). But still stuck on heroku: only doing `syncdb` there is yielding me a database error: DatabaseError at /

relation "links_link" does not exist
LINE 1: ... "url", SUM("links_vote"."value") AS "votes" FROM "links_lin

Comment: So when I syncdb on Heroku and choose "no" to set up a super user, the deployment works, no error is thrown. Can you explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved via running `heroku config:set ON_HEROKU=1`. In my settings.py file, I used sqlite3 locally, but reverted to postgres when on Heroku. Setting ON_HEROKU to 1 *before* running syncdb, hence, solved the problem for me.